# How to fix conflicting pulldown to refresh gesture and scrolling down in ReactNative?

Tags: react-native, scrollview, pull-to-refresh

I'm continuing a previous developer's work. After login, it has a screen that has structure generally like this:

```
index's render
- ScrollView + RefreshControl
  - IndexRoute
    - Tab 1 screen
      - ScrollView
        - Content
    - Tab 2 screen
      - ScrollView
        - Content
    - Tab 3 screen
      - ScrollView
        - Content
```

The problem here is the nested ScrollView situation. The outer ScrollView + RefreshControl pulldown to refresh listener is 'hijacking' the inside ScrollView's scrolling down gesture listener. So whenever the user is trying to scrolling the content up by swiping down, the pulldown to refresh is triggered instead.

From my guess, the way to fix this is by changing the structure like this:

```
index's render
- View
  - IndexRoute
    - Tab 1 screen
      - ScrollView + RefreshControl
        - Content
    - Tab 2 screen
      - ScrollView + RefreshControl
        - Content
    - Tab 3 screen
      - ScrollView + RefreshControl
        - Content
```

But is there any way to resolve this issue without rehauling the structure into moving refresh control into each of the child scroll view and change the root scroll view into ordinary view?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add the prop `nestedScrollEnabled` to both the outer and the inner ScrollViews.

Comment: I see. In the end, I used workaround for this (e.g. not having nested scrollviews). But if I ever in similar situation again, I'll try your advice.

Comment: This solved my issue of having `ScrollView` and scrollable table inside it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to listen to the `onScroll` events of the `ScrollViews`, and depending on the rules you want to enforce, disable the scrolling behavior on the outer one or all the others.

Like if you are on the top of the `ScrollView` of one of the tabs, scrolling down should disable its own scroll and trigger the refresh of the outer one, but if you' re not a the top, the outer one should have its scroll disable to allow the tab to be navigated without triggering a refresh.

Play around with the `scrollEnabled` and `onScroll` props on `ScrollView` to disable a specific scroll depending on your needs.